# How to execute all text files from the folder in curl?

Tags: batch-file, curl, cmd

I'm trying to execute all .txt files in my folder instead of doing this individually, I tried few different ways but still can not get this to work. Here is my command what I used in Command prompt:

```
C:\curl>curl.exe -T E:\ABCD\one\two\three\*.txt -u USERNAME:PASSWORD ftp://ftp.test.com/One/*.txt
```

Please if you know what I should change to get this to work Please let me know.

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
for %%# in ("E:\ABCD\one\two\three\*.txt") do  curl.exe -T "%%~f#" -u USERNAME:PASSWORD ftp://ftp.test.com/One/%%~nx#
```

this can be used for batch script
for command line use single `%`

Comment: Thanks a lot! This works for all my txt files. I have one more question. How I can use this script to run in Task Scheduler? Where I should implement this script and in what format? Thanks in advance!

Comment: @user3023588 you just can open the task scheduler UI and point to to the bat (dont forget to set also a work dir) and choose the settings you want...

Comment: I tried but that did not work for me. Can you provide an example by any chance?